# Update a nested array in MongoDB with Node.JS Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB with this structure:

```
> db.daisy.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d6fc2bca33d05a19448a39"),
    "name" : "Test Song",
    "genre" : "Rock",
    "count" : "1",
    "lyrics" : [
        {
            "line" : "1",
            "lyric" : "first lyric"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add more lyrics to the song. I have been struggling through the APIs but I just can't seem to get it. I am trying to update it like this

```
router.post('/updatelyric/:id', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var songID = req.params.id;
    console.log(req.params.id)
    db.collection('daisy').update({
        _id: songID
    }, {
        $push: {
            lyrics: req.body
        }
    }, function(err, result) {
        res.send((err === null) ? {msg: ''} : {msg: err});
    });
});
```

I am getting 200 codes for my posts, but nothing happens in my Mongo.
Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you check the `result`  object to see how many records were updated?

Comment: status will be 200 because you are returning the response, but check for the err it will be showing some error. You are retrieving the songId from the req object then it will be string format, you have to convert it into mongoDb object since _id is in id form